# How to check if email is authorized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble constructing a SQL query (I'm using SSMS) that I use in my application.

Description of the situation: the result is to return T if the email is authorized to send an email.

Scope:

(a) the query is to return T if:

- mail is not domain specific ( i.e. its domain is not in table: DOMAINS).
- mail is a domain (i.e. its domain is in the table: DOMAINS) and mail is in the table: AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN.

b) the query should return nothing if the e-mail is a domain but it is NOT in the table: AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN.

Before mentioned tables:

1. DOMAINS - contains domains which are the pattern for checking
   eg:

```
test.com
test2.com
test3.com
```

2. AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN - contains specific emails which are domain specific.

The query I currently have is not working well:

```
select top 1 case
when UPPER('john.smith1@test1.com') like Concat('%',C_DOMAIN_NAME) then 
case when (UPPER(C_EMAIL_ADDRESS) = UPPER('john.smith1@test1.com')) then 'T' END
else
'T'
END
as aaa
FROM DOMAINS, AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN
```

The email is a domain (it is in the table: DOMAINS) but it is not in the table: AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN, and the query returns T anyway ( it should return nothing).
What am I doing wrong?

edit:
Both tables are independent of each other and have one column each  which are listed above.

```
table DOMAINS has column: C_DOMAIN_NAME

table AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN has column: C_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Please add complete [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) for the tables `DOMAINS` and `AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN`, because no one should guess how they are defined when they start commenting on this question.

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb142ce4d1d9805202c681e1efb08073) seems to do what you need.

```
drop table if exists domains;
drop table if exists authorized_domain;

create table domains ( C_DOMAIN_NAME varchar(100));
create table authorized_domain (C_EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar(100));

insert into domains values ('test.com'),('test2.com'),('test3.com');
insert into authorized_domain values 
    ('angela@test.com'),
    ('bert@test2.com'),
    ('boris@test2.com'),
    ('claudia@test3.com'),
    ('dirk@test4.com'),
    ('edward@example.com');

select * from domains;
select * from authorized_domain;

DECLARE @testemail varchar(100) = 'boris@test2.com'; 
SELECT 'T' as aaa 
FROM authorized_domain
LEFT JOIN  DOMAINS ON C_EMAIL_ADDRESS like CONCAT('%',C_DOMAIN_NAME)
LEFT JOIN (
   select name, domain
   from (
     select 
       value as name, 
       lead(value) over (order by x.x) as domain
     from (select row_number() over (order by value) x, value from string_split(@testemail,'@')) x
   ) y where not name is null and not domain is null
) z ON C_EMAIL_ADDRESS = concat(z.name,'@',z.domain)
where C_EMAIL_ADDRESS = @testemail
;
```

the input emailaddress (i.e. 'boris@test2.com`) is split in it's` name`and`domain` with this SQL:

```
DECLARE @testemail varchar(100) = 'boras@test2.com';
select name, domain
   from (
     select 
       value as name, 
       lead(value) over (order by x.x) as domain
     from (select row_number() over (order by value) x, value from string_split(@testemail,'@')) x
   ) y where not name is null and not domain is null
```

which outputs:

| name | domain |
| --- | --- |
| boris | test2.com |

EDIT: Hopefully all rules apply with this edit (same tables used as above):

I did leave my test stuff in the query, in the comments...

```
DECLARE @testemail2 varchar(100) = 'boris@test2.com';
select 'T' as aaa   -- C_EMAIL_ADDRESS, C_DOMAIN_NAME,2
from authorized_domain
left join domains on C_DOMAIN_NAME =  substring(C_EMAIL_ADDRESS,CHARINDEX('@',C_EMAIL_ADDRESS)+1,100)
where ( C_EMAIL_ADDRESS = @testemail2 and not C_DOMAIN_NAME is null ) -- a1
   or ( C_EMAIL_ADDRESS = @testemail2 and C_DOMAIN_NAME is null )     -- a2
union all
select distinct 'T' as aaa   -- distinct @testemail2,substring(@testemail2,CHARINDEX('@',@testemail2)+1,100),1
from domains where substring(@testemail2,CHARINDEX('@',@testemail2)+1,100) NOT IN (select C_DOMAIN_NAME from domains)
;
```

A table with the results for some different email addresses:

| email address | result |
| --- | --- |
| boris@test2.com | T |
| borAs@test2.com |  |
| boris@test5.com | T |
| borAs@test5.com | T |

Comment: but if the email is not domain, it should always return 'T' - and using your query and changing boris@test2.com to 'boris@test5.com' (domain test5.com is not available) it should return 'T' -  your query is not working in this way beacuse it returns nothing.

Comment: It is returning nothing because of "b) the query should return nothing if the e-mail is a domain but it is NOT in the table: AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN." and `boris@test5.com` is not in `AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN` ?

Comment: point b) the query should return nothing if the e-mail is a domain (should be added: so is in table ```domains```)  but it is NOT in the table: ```AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN```." - and boris@test5.com has domain:test5.com which is not in domains table - so it is point:  a) he query is to return T if:

    mail is not domain specific ( i.e. its domain is not in table: ```DOMAINS```).

Comment: added a second try... 

Comment: yes, it is working. I try resolve it on my own and I want to know what do you think about this solution: ```select top 1 'T' as aaa from AUTHORIZED_DOMAIN, DOMAINS 
where (UPPER(C_EMAIL_ADDRESS) = UPPER('test@test.com'))
or not exists 
(select * from DOMAINS where UPPER('test@test.com') like Concat('%',C_DOMAIN_NAME))``` ?

Comment: I do not have enough data to test if there is a performance difference between your solution and mine, you could check if there is, and choose the solution that has the best performance. (and works!)